# FILTER function not allowing two criteria on one column

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

Say I have the following table, and I want to get all rows where COL2 = 2 and 3

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | COL1 | COL2 |
| 2 | A | 2 |
| 3 | S | 3 |
| 4 | F | 4 |
| 5 | E | 5 |

When I run the following formula:
=FILTER($A$2:$B$5,(B2:B5=2)*(B2:B5=3),"No Match")

I get "No Match". It seems when I remove one of the criteria, there is no issue with meeting the other criteria. However it seems like I cannot run both criteria concurrently. Anyone know the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

Solved: I should be using a `+` operator between the two criteria, not a `*`.